# What is the equivalent of 'git reset --hard commit' in SVN?

Tags: svn

I am investigating a Subversion repository for research purposes, and I would like to change the working directory to a specific revision (the whole thing). To make you more aware, I am not committing nor doing anything with the repository. I am just checking the history.

I investigated a Git repository before, and I used to type the following command:

```
git reset --hard #{commitId}
```

And it changes the whole repository for me which is what I am looking for. I tried and searched for something equivalent in Subversion, but I couldn't find it. I tried:

```
svn checkout -r #{revisionNo} url
```

I also tried:

```
svn update -r #{revisionNo}
```

But it didn't give the result I wanted. I exactly want going back to see the files at that time.

How can this be done?

Comment: If I understood correctly, `svn update` should do—assuming that's not the actual command (you don't want any `#` prefix). How is the result different from what you expect?

Comment: I expected the whole structure will change. So did [svn log --verbose -REV], and I got a list of the files changes in this REV (full path), then I did [svn update -REV] for the same REV number, I should be able to access the files as specified in the path provided but actually I cannot. Because the structure didn't change. Hopefully is clear what I am trying to say.

Comment: Never mind about #, it is ruby syntax.

Comment: Is the revision number the only thing that changes? Is the old code in the same URL?

Comment: I didn't get you first question reqarding revision number. I guess yes, but I am not sure, as I said I am investigating but I don't know if the authors changed the url.

Comment: What problem with `svn update -r #{revisionNo}` ? It should works as you expect. Possible you try update only working copy subset? You should either execute `svn up -r R` in working copy root or with full path of wc root: `svn up -r R c:\my_wc`

Comment: @SergeyAzarkevich Is there a special meaning for "trunk" is svn? Because whenever I check the files changes, I got "trunk" folder as the first folder, which is not actually exist in the structure. But everything after is correct

Comment: Nothing special. By convention it is 'main' branch, like master in git. May be you checkout part of repo (say `repo/branches/branch1`) and then expect that after update to revision R you see content of `repo/trunk` because in R changes was made in `trunk` ? Then no, svn does not work like this. You can checkout whole repository and in this case uptade to R will modify files in trunk/

Comment: Yes I think you are right. I noticed that some repositories contain trunk in their checkout command, and so I just got the trunk folder. But they didn't provide the whole command which contain trunk and other folders.